# Running data for 1 year dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a procedure where I have calls data for each day. From this procedure I wrote another procedure to insert and update in the destination table.

We have a job which runs for every day. But now I need to run the data for past 1 year (each day).

Below are my parameters in insert update procedure - if I need to get data for 18th my parameters values are like below

```
,@StartDate datetime = '2020-04-18'
,@EndDate datetime = '2020-04-19'
,@SkillLevel varchar(10)='Total'
,@Region varchar(20) = 'US'
```

If I need to get data for 17th my parameters values are like below

```
,@StartDate datetime = '2020-04-17'
,@EndDate datetime = '2020-04-18'
,@SkillLevel varchar(10)='Total'
,@Region varchar(20) = 'US'
```

Like this to get data for last 1 year I need to run the code for 365 days which takes huge effort

Could anyone suggest how to pass dates individually for 1 year with some loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [StartDate] DATE
);

DECLARE @BegDate DATE
       ,@EndDate DATE;

SELECT @BegDate = '2020-01-01'
      ,@EndDate = '2020-12-31';

DECLARE @EndNumber BIGINT;

SELECT @EndNumber = DATEDIFF(DAY, @BegDate, @EndDate);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([StartDate])
SELECT TOP (@EndNumber) DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY T1.[number])-1, @BegDate)
FROM master..spt_values T1 
CROSS JOIN master..spt_values T2;

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @DataSource)
BEGIN;

    SELECT TOP 1 @BegDate = [StartDate]
                ,@EndDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, [StartDate])
    FROM @DataSource; 

    --

    EXEC [stored_precedure]  @StartDate = @BegDate
                            ,@EndDate = @EndDate
                            ,@SkillLevel ='Total'
                            ,@Region = 'ES'


    --

    DELETE FROM @DataSource
    WHERE [StartDate] = @BegDate;

END;
```